# categorizing string according to length in Python

Tags: string, list, python-2.7

I have given n different strings. I have to form different lists of strings according to the list. For example, given strings are `this,that,is,am,are,i,j` then four lists should be generated like:

```
s[1] = [i,j]
s[2] = [is,am]
s[3] = [are]
s[4] = [this,that]
```

These lists must be easily accessible by their index (in this case, length)

Comment: I have initialized a dictionary and then while taking the string from user, I have checked for string length then adding that string to dic[string length] list.

Comment: In what way does that not fulfill the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

words = ['this','that','is','am','are','i','j']

with_lengths = [(word, len(word)) for word in words]
output = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in with_lengths:
  output[v].append(k)

for key in output:
  print '%i -> %s' % (key, output[key])
```

Output:

```
1 -> ['i', 'j']
2 -> ['is', 'am']
3 -> ['are']
4 -> ['this', 'that']
```